# How do I print the maximum value in a "for" loop?

Tags: python

Basically what I need is for my code to print the tuple with the highest value of "promedio" variable if I introduce a dictionary in my function. I'm stuck, because my code only prints the latest result and not the highest one, here is it:

```
def mejor_promedio_anual(datos: dict):
empleados = datos
for clave in empleados:
    nombre_empleado = empleados[clave]["nombre_emp"]
    primeras_tres:str = empleados[clave]["nombre_emp"][0:3]
    cedula = int(empleados[clave]["cedula"])
    digitos_cedula = [int(n) for n in str(cedula)]
    pares_int = [x for x in digitos_cedula if x%2 == 0]
    sumatoria_impares = sum([x for x in digitos_cedula if x%2 != 0])
    multip_impares = "".join([str(num*sumatoria_impares) for num in pares_int])
        #Codigo Empleado
    codigo_unico:str = primeras_tres + multip_impares

    ventas_totales = 0
    for a in empleados[clave]["ventas"]:
        for b in a.values():
            for value in b.values():
                ventas_totales+=value
    promedio = round(ventas_totales/48, 2)
    tupla = (codigo_unico, nombre_empleado, promedio)
return tupla
```

This is my function, and I'm going to add a dictionary and then do the print, which is this:

```
datos = {
    "Ju1234": {
        "nombre_emp": 'Juan',
        "cedula": '12345679',
        "edad": '28',
        "ventas": [
            {
                "enero": {
                    "camisas": 1500000,
                    "jeans": 2450000,
                    "vestidos": 800000,
                    "zapatos": 1300000
                }
            },
            {
                "febrero": {
                    "camisas": 134000,
                    "jeans": 600000,
                    "vestidos": 700000,
                    "zapatos": 900000
                }
            },
            {
                "marzo": {
                    "camisas": 1000000,
                    "jeans": 1400000,
                    "vestidos": 1600000,
                    "zapatos": 1800000
                }
            },
            {
                "abril": {
                    "camisas": 1900000,
                    "jeans": 2450000,
                    "vestidos": 1400000,
                    "zapatos": 300000
                }
            },
            {
                "mayo": {
                    "camisas": 1800000,
                    "jeans": 2750000,
                    "vestidos": 1200000,
                    "zapatos": 200000
                }
            },
            {
                "junio": {
                    "camisas": 1700000,
                    "jeans": 2000000,
                    "vestidos": 1900000,
                    "zapatos": 500000
                }
            },
            {
                "julio": {
                    "camisas": 1600000,
                    "jeans": 2780000,
                    "vestidos": 1500000,
                    "zapatos": 700000
                }
            },
            {
                "agosto": {
                    "camisas": 1500000,
                    "jeans": 2250000,
                    "vestidos": 1100000,
                    "zapatos": 200000
                }
            },
            {
                "septiembre": {
                    "camisas": 1100000,
                    "jeans": 2540000,
                    "vestidos": 1200000,
                    "zapatos": 400000
                }
            },
            {
                "octubre": {
                    "camisas": 1400000,
                    "jeans": 2120000,
                    "vestidos": 1400000,
                    "zapatos": 500000
                }
            },
            {
                "noviembre": {
                    "camisas": 1300000,
                    "jeans": 2230000,
                    "vestidos": 1700000,
                    "zapatos": 200000
                }
            },
            {
                "diciembre": {
                    "camisas": 1000000,
                    "jeans": 2480000,
                    "vestidos": 1800000,
                    "zapatos": 100000
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "Ma9876": {
        "nombre_emp": 'Martha',
        "cedula": '987654321',
        "edad": '25',
        "ventas": [
            {
                "enero": {
                    "camisas": 980000,
                    "jeans": 4200000,
                    "vestidos": 940000,
                    "zapatos": 500000
                }
            },
            {
                "febrero": {
                    "camisas": 910000,
                    "jeans": 6400000,
                    "vestidos": 140000,
                    "zapatos": 480000
                }
            },
            {
                "marzo": {
                    "camisas": 920000,
                    "jeans": 4300000,
                    "vestidos": 240000,
                    "zapatos": 410000
                }
            },
            {
                "abril": {
                    "camisas": 980000,
                    "jeans": 4200000,
                    "vestidos": 540000,
                    "zapatos": 402000
                }
            },
            {
                "mayo": {
                    "camisas": 920000,
                    "jeans": 4700000,
                    "vestidos": 540000,
                    "zapatos": 980000
                }
            },
            {
                "junio": {
                    "camisas": 900000,
                    "jeans": 4600000,
                    "vestidos": 650000,
                    "zapatos": 290000
                }
            },
            {
                "julio": {
                    "camisas": 890000,
                    "jeans": 4200000,
                    "vestidos": 190000,
                    "zapatos": 720000
                }
            },
            {
                "agosto": {
                    "camisas": 130000,
                    "jeans": 9200000,
                    "vestidos": 960000,
                    "zapatos": 870000
                }
            },
            {
                "septiembre": {
                    "camisas": 210000,
                    "jeans": 5400000,
                    "vestidos": 180000,
                    "zapatos": 980000
                }
            },
            {
                "octubre": {
                    "camisas": 250000,
                    "jeans": 3400000,
                    "vestidos": 140000,
                    "zapatos": 450000
                }
            },
            {
                "noviembre": {
                    "camisas": 430000,
                    "jeans": 1500000,
                    "vestidos": 100000,
                    "zapatos": 420000
                }
            },
            {
                "diciembre": {
                    "camisas": 560000,
                    "jeans": 4500000,
                    "vestidos": 720000,
                    "zapatos": 400000
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
print(mejor_promedio_anual(datos))
```

If execute this code, it prints the tuple ('Mar20015010050', 'Martha', 1602541.67), which is the last one in the loop (second dictionary key), but I need my code to print the tuple which has the highest "promedio", for any values I add to my dictionary, how do I do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why your variable names are spanish? Where is `promedio` in your input dictionary? What's the output needed, starting from that input?

Comment: Because the course I'm taking is in spanish. I'm being as clear as I can, sorry if it isn't enough. 
Here I go again: `promedio` is an internal variable in the function, and the returned tuple will be `tupla = (codigo_unico, nombre_empleado, promedio)`. What I need, basically, is for my function to return the tupla with the highest `promedio` value after the for loop. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

1. Create an empty list before the for loop
2. Append every tupla result into that list
3. Afterwards use `max(list, key=lambda t: t[2])` to find the largest (sorted by the third value in the tuple), and return that

or:

1. Create a "current_largest_tupla" variable (with a placeholder of 0)
2. In the for loop, check each result to see if it is larger than the max, and replace if so
3. At the end, return that value

Comment: Refer https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_max.asp in order to know more about `max` function

Comment: Thanks so much, so I need to do before the for a `empty_list = [ ]` and then, in the for loop do `empty_list.append(tupla)`. But how do I use the `max`? Just `my_variable = max(empty_list)`?

Little question: the `my_variable = max(empty_list)` will return the max tuple based on which criteria? how do I make sure it will choose the tuple with highest `promedio` always?

Comment: `my_variable = max(empty_list, key="promedio")` should do you

Comment: Thanks. The thing is that "promedio" is a variable inside the function, not a key. Should I only do `my_variable = max(empty_list, promedio)` instead?

Comment: Having looked a bit closer, seems like you're saving the `promedio` variable as the third item in the `tupla`, so `my_variable = max(list, key=lambda t: t[2])` will access the third item from the tuple (you can pass lambda functions into max as the key)